# Drawing line in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, canvas

Firefox29 and IE9 render this perfectly, but chrome doesn't. Is this caused by a bug?

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.lineTo( 593.3050280683777 ,  32.44333714926335 ); 
....
ctx.lineTo( 706.7133058984912 ,  188.50554181134356 ); 
ctx.stroke();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/drps/73qxS/

Chrome 34.0.1847.131:

[image: chrome(34.0.1847.131) screenshot]

Firefox:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIWFG.png]

Comment: Seem the same to me...? (although using Canary). Please include a snapshot of what you have in Chrome compared to the others (just link to the images f.ex. using imgur.com and we'll help you inline them).

Comment: i've added screenshot in my first post

Comment: By the way, i've just noticed that when i increase or decrease any coordinate by 0.01 or 0.02(in some cases) it renders perfectly in chrome

Comment: how it looks in firefox http://i.imgur.com/Ru4LJ9P.png

Comment: It's most likely an issue with current version Chrome. As mentioned, it's gone with Canary (as far as I can see) so it's just a time question before it will be available in the public version as well (unless it is related to hardware acc. etc). I would in any case report it to the Chromium team at their bug reporting page (go f.ex via Chrome about menu).

Comment: it is perfect in chromium 53.0.2785.143 Built on Ubuntu